# Rails crons task only running in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a task defined in `crons.rake` but this task only runs in production mode. how can I got this running in dev mode?

```
task(:generate_mindmails => :environment) do
```

Comment: Why doesn't it run in development mode? Is there an error message?

Comment: Its not supposed to run in development mode by default

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I whould suggest you to use the `whenever` gem instead. It can be configured more comfortable. Like this:

```
every 5.hours do
  runner "MyModel.my_method", :environment => :development
end
```

You can install it by adding `gem 'whenever'` to your `Gemfile` then run `bundle install`. You should read the documentation or at least the `README.md` of the github project.

// You can also run it in both environments:

```
every 5.hours do
  runner "MyModel.my_method", :environment => :development
  runner "MyModel.my_method", :environment => :production
end
```

Comment: Yes I'm using whenever thanks for that hint, I try it, can I configure it that it runs in dev and in production?

Answer (score 4):

Simply set the environment before executing the command:

```
$ RAILS_ENV=development rake generate_mindmails
```